# Add body class to list of pages based on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add a body class to a list of pages that have a specific URL. For example, if the URL is /page1.html, /page2.html, /page3.html, /page4.html etc. etc. I would like to add a class to the body tag.

The code I have works but it's very bloated. Is there a way to write this more elegantly? All in all, I will need to check 10 different URLs.

```
(function($) {
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('page1.html') > -1 ||
         document.location.href.indexOf('page2.html') > -1 || 
         document.location.href.indexOf('page3.html') > -1 ||
         document.location.href.indexOf('page4.html') > -1 ) {
             $('body').addClass('testclass');
    }
}(jQuery));
```

It can be jQuery or vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:-

```
const pages = ['page1.html', 'page2.html', 'page3.html', 'page4.html'];

(function($) {
    pages.forEach(item => {
        if(document.location.href.indexOf(item) >=0)  {
            $('body').addClass('testclass');
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the urls to an array and loop through the array:

```
var urls = ["page1.html", "page2.html", "page3.html", "page4.html"];
var href = document.location.href;
for (var i=0; i<urls.length; ++i) {
    if (href.indexOf(urls[i]) > -1)  {
      $('body').addClass('testclass');
    }
}
```

if the pages are all in the same format, just with a number, you could build them dynmically, but you have less control over adding/removing pages, eg:

```
var href = document.location.href;
for (var i=1; i<=4; ++i) {
    if (href.indexOf("page" + i + ".html") > -1)  {
      $('body').addClass('testclass');
    }
}
```

There are fancier ways of formatting these using array manipulations, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant way to do this is to use `Array.some()`

```
(function($) {
    const pages = ['page1.html', 'page2.html' /* add whatever here */];

    if (pages.some(page => document.location.href.indexOf(page) > -1)) {
       $('body').addClass('testclass');
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Nice and succinct, but I wish they hadn't called it `some` as, in English, `some>1` (ie 2 or more, not 1, normally more than 2) which is not the case in javascript; other systems called this `.any`

Comment: Coming from Scala, I have trouble remembering this function name too...

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
const pages = ['page1.html', 'page2.html', 'page3.html', 'page4.html'];

$('body').addClass(pages.find(page => ($(location).attr('pathname').includes(page))) && 'testclass');
```